# Eclipse Plugin Set Image icon for a custom dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I made a custom Eclipse plugin that uses and displays multiple dialogs, and I want to know if I could set the top left icon image with the one I use in the plugin's `icons` folder. I want to get that icon and set it instead of the default one that Eclipse uses.
I'm overriding the `configureShell()` method to change the dialog title, and I also want to change the icon.

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell parent){
    super.configureShell(parent);
    parent.setText("Choose variant...");
    Image icon = new Image(parent.getDisplay(), "icons/best.gif"); - this method does not work as it cannot find the file
    parent.setImage(icon);
}
```

I also tried using the `getClass().getResource("best.gif")` and having the image in the same package, still can't find the location I'm giving(FileNotFoundException), and also, the `Image` constructor does not accept URL objects.

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell parent){
    super.configureShell(parent);
    parent.setText("Choose variant...");
    Image icon = new Image(parent.getDisplay(), getClass().getResource("icons/best.gif"));
    parent.setImage(icon);
}
```

Is there a way to use the icon that I already have in my eclipse plugin?
The main problem is getting the icon from the `icons` folder of the plugin and making it a `Image` object.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register the icon in your plugins [activator class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857476/when-to-choose-generate-an-activator-when-creating-a-new-eclipse-plugin-pro) like this:

```
@Override
protected void initializeImageRegistry(final ImageRegistry reg) {
    reg.put(IMAGE_PATH, imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, IMAGE_PATH));
}
```

The image path is relative to your plugin, e.g. `icons/icon.png`.

You can access these images via the activator class as well:

```
final Image image = MyActivatorClass.getDefault().getImageRegistry().get(IMAGE_PATH);
myShell.setImage(image);
```

(Note that I used the image path as key in the image registry, you do not have to do it like this but it makes everything a little bit less complicated by just using the same static `String`.)

Comment: Yep, it worked, thanks you. I can register multiple images as well?

Comment: Yes you can. Also have a look at gregs answer, your activator class must extend `AbstractUIPlugin` I missed that step.

Answer (score 2):

For an Eclipse plugin you use the `FileLocator` class to find resources in your plugin.

For an image use something like:

```
String path = "icons/best.gif";

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);

ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

Image image = desc.createImage();
```

Note: You must arrange for the image to be disposed when no longer needed.

If your activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin` you can also use the `ImageRegistry` available from that. The registry will deal with disposing.

Be sure that the `icons` directory is listed in the `build.properties` file. Missing this will causes issues when you export your plugin.

Comment: It worked with the `Activator`'s `Image Registry`. Thanks for the advice as well.